# ValueError: Target is multiclass but average='binary' error for binary data

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, precision-recall

I encountered an issue when using the `recall_score()` function from scikit-learn in a binary classification scenario. Despite having binary target data (`y_test` containing only 0s and 1s), I received the following error message:

```
ValueError: Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose another average setting, one of [None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted'].
```

The error occurs specifically on the line of code:

```
recall_ANOVA = recall_score(y_test, np.round(best_model_name_ANOVA.predict(X_test[selected_features_ANOVA]), 0))
```

My scikit version is 1.1.3

`type_of_target(y_test)` does return `'binary'`

I have verified that `y_test` is indeed binary, and this issue only appears when a certain number of features is set beforehand in my code. I suspect it might be a bug or unexpected behavior.

Why does this error occur in a binary classification scenario and how to resolve it? Is this possibly a bug in scikit-learn, or am I missing something in my code?

Comment: We cannot rely on your assurance that `y_test` is indeed binary; please post a [mre].